# Codename One use with VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, codenameone

Is there any way to use CN1 with VSCode? I find the IDE increasingly more beautiful, editable, usable and lightweight.

If not, are there any plans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have any plans at this time to support VSCode (used it myself for some non-Java code and I personally don't share your enthusiasm for it). If it supports Ant projects you can just open any Codename One project with it and use it.

All Codename One projects are ant projects that include targets for sending a build to any platform. The simulator etc. are all in the JavaSE.jar. You can look at the configuration for that in the properties file of the project.

**EDIT:**
You compile a Codename One app for the simulator by invoking `ant jar`. You can then run the resulting jar using

`java -classpath lib/CLDC11.jar:lib/CodenameOne.jar:lib/CodenameOne_SRC.zip:lib/impl/cls:lib/impl/stubs:JavaSE.jar:native/internal_tmp:YOUR_JAR_NAME_HERE com.codename1.impl.javase.Simulator`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Shai.. I am aware that not everyone shares my enthusiasm for VSCode. Will the simulator also run in VSCode? I will give it a shot when I have some spare time .... where is the properties file you speak of located?

Comment: Yes, it's under the nbproject directory

Comment: I am actually trying to make this work. Where would I start? Seems the structure from the newer projects differs, since I was able to locate the nbproject directory only in the eclipse folder of the old ones, dated 2019. For a start, I opened the project folder in VSCode, but I got a classpath error and I don't know where to put and how to access the relevant properties and jar files, and run the project with the simulator.

Comment: You should use the NetBeans project as the baseline not the eclipse project which is more of a hack. IntelliJ also uses the NetBeans project structure so it's a better overall build.xml file.

Comment: Hello Shai, please throw more light on how to run the simulator in VSCode.

Comment: Hi @ShaiAlmog, in the Codename One initializr, IDE is there the VSCode option, so you say have no plans to add vscode support??? Anyway, I try to run like a "maven" project, but I got some errors... There is another way to use CN1 with VSCode?

Comment: There's currently an issue with the maven support on vscode. We're looking at it.

Comment: Currently, I run the simulator (vscode) using the script run.sh located at the root of the project, passing "simulator" as a parameter (ex: ./run.sh simulator). But now a need to run the simulator in Debug mode.  I don't see any option that allows me to do that. Is It possible to run the simulator in debug mode using vscode?

Comment: Try creating a new project in https://start.codenameone.com/ and selecting "start" then copy over the dependencies and code. It should work out of the box.